# overwrite malloc/free in dlopen-ed library

Tags: linux, malloc, libc, dlopen

I have a shared library - `plugin.so`, which is `dlopen`-ed by the host program with flag `RTLD_LOCAL`, I have my own memory operation functions defined in that library:

```
void *plugin_malloc(size_t size) { /* ... */ }
void plugin_free(void *ptr) { /* ... */ }
```

What I need is to replace ALL `malloc/free` calls in `plugin.so` with my own `plugin_malloc/plugin_free`, I tried using GCC's alias attribute extension:

```
void *malloc(size_t) __attribute__((alias("plugin_malloc"), used))
void free(void*) __attribute__((alias("plugin_free"), used))
```

However, this only works when the library is linked into the host program, but not work with the `dlopen` way.

I'm on Linux with compiler GCC-4.8.5, and I have the source code of `plugin.so` and can modify it as I like, but I **cannot modify the host program**, and replace `malloc/free` not only in `plugin.so` but also in entire program is also acceptable.

So, is there any solution? Thanks.

---

EDIT: **I also have no permission to modify the host program's startup arguments, environment variables**, what I can do is just providing the `plugin.so` to guys who own the host program, and they run the host program and `dlopen` my `plugin.so`.

Comment: You could achieve this with the LD_PRELOAD trick: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick

Comment: @Leo Sorry, I cannot do that as I have no permission to run that program, all I can do is providing the `plugin.so` to guys who own the host program, I added this info to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I need is to replace ALL malloc/free calls in plugin.so with my own plugin_malloc/plugin_free,

This is trivial to do.

Suppose you have `foo.o` and `plugin_malloc.o` that are linked into `plugin.so`. The `foo.o` uses `malloc` and `free`, while `plugin.o` defines `plugin_malloc` and  `plugin_free`.

Then:

```
objcopy --redefine-sym malloc=plugin_malloc --redefine-sym free=plugin_free foo.o foo2.o
gcc -shared -fPIC plugin.o foo2.o -o plugin.so
```

Voila: all references to `malloc` and `free` in `foo.o` have been replaced. Enjoy.

**Update:**

> if I call a glibc function which allocates memory and needs to be freed in my code, the program crashes. e.g. char *s = strdup("hello"); free(s); because strdup calls glibc's malloc, but the later free is my plugin_free

There are a few ways, only some of which satisfy your other constraints:

1. you must replace *all* `malloc`s and `free`s with your own for the *entire* program (e.g. via `LD_PRELOAD`, or by statically linking `malloc` implementation into the main executable), or
2. you must ensure that you *don't* call any function that allocates memory via `malloc` that you expect to `free` later, or
3. for any such calls to `stdup` or `asprintf` etc., when you want to deallocate this memory, you must call `__libc_free` rather than `plugin_free`, or
4. in `plugin_malloc`, pad all memory you allocate with 16 extra byte header (for alignment) write magic number to the start of the block, and return a pointer past the header to the caller. In `plugin_free`, check for proper alignment, then check the header for magic number. If it's there, subtract 16 from the pointer and use the rest of `plugin_free` to free the memory. If the magic number is not there, assume the pointer didn't come from `plugin_malloc`, and call `__libc_free` on it instead.
5. In `plugin_malloc` keep track of all the blocks you've ever allocated. In `plugin_free` check that list, and use `__libc_free` if the pointer is not on the list.

Since you have all sources for your plugin, either solution 2 or 3 should be doable, but obviously requires that you audit every call to `free` to see where the memory came from.

Variants 4 and 5 don't require such audit, but don't cleanly separate memory allocated by plugin from that allocated by the main program.

Don't forget about other ways to allocate memory: `realloc`, `memalign`, `posix_memalign`, etc.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your great solution, I never realized I can do this! But there is a problem: if I call a glibc function which allocates memory and needs to be freed in my code, the program crashes. e.g. `char *s = strdup("hello"); free(s);` because `strdup` calls glibc's `malloc`, but the later `free` is my `plugin_free`, any way to solve this?

Comment: @KelvinHu There is no easy way. I've updated the answer with some possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you provide a pair of functions named malloc and free (instead of plugin_malloc for example), in a shared library compiled with `-fPIC`, then you just need to `LD_PRELOAD` it when calling your client app:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/path/mymalloc.so executable
```

or export it before calling your client:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/mymalloc.so
executable
```

more details:

- [man ld.so](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html)
- [The LD_PRELOAD trick](http://www.goldsborough.me/c/low-level/kernel/2016/08/29/16-48-53-the_-ld_preload-_trick/)

[UPDATE]

Considering you cannot change the environment but only replace the dynamic library and nothing else then you may be able to:

- find where malloc/free are in memory
- replace the original functions entry code for a jmp to your own functions

Your library gonna need an initialization function to do this dirty work. Check the constructor attribute [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html). Replacing the code may not be allowed, though.

Another possibility to explore(oit?): if the code is using glibc you can try to provide a [__malloc_hook](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_hook.3.html) in your library instead.

Yet another: seize the application control in your library init function never returning from it and then execute the application again with your custom setup.

I cannot come out with any other possibility, for now, considering your constraints.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot do that as I have no permission to run that program, all I can do is providing the `plugin.so` to guys who own the host program, I added this info to the post.

Comment: no, you didn't say you cannot change the environment.

Comment: Yes, it's my fault, now I appended that to the post.

Comment: So... change the `.text` segment writable, find the address of `malloc/free`, and then write a `JMP plugin_malloc/plugin_free` instruction at the start of function? seems doable, but it's really a dirty solution...

Comment: it is dirty and hacky. it looks like cracking someone else's code. however, your constraints make you look like you are actually trying to hack someone else's code. aren't you? :)

Comment: Thanks for your several advice, but I think I will try to talk to those guys first, to persuade them to link the so into the host program, that should be the most elegant way, though there must be a tough communication...

Comment: you could present them the alternatives. I think they are bad enough to convince them easily :)